# Python Newspaper Package - not failing on invalid URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use python (3.5) newspaper package to download article from CNN. Program below:

```
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Config, Article, Source
import requests

c = Config()
c.browser_user_agent = 'test/1.1'
c.http_success_only = True

URL = 'http://rss.cnn1sdfs.com/c/35494/f/676993/s/4ddb6116/sc/14/l/0Ledition0Bcnn0N0C20A160C0A20C250Chealth0Ce0Ecigarette0Eexplodes0Ein0Emans0Epocket0Cindex0Bhtml0Deref0Fedition/story01.htm'

a = Article(url=URL,config=c)
a.download()

# response = requests.get(URL)
# response.raise_for_status()
```

Even though the DNS couldnot be resolved this program does not fail!

I looked at newspaper code [here](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/network.py)

```
def get_html(url, config=None, response=None):
    """Retrieves the html for either a url or a response object. All html
    extractions MUST come from this method due to some intricies in the
    requests module. To get the encoding, requests only uses the HTTP header
    encoding declaration requests.utils.get_encoding_from_headers() and reverts
    to ISO-8859-1 if it doesn't find one. This results in incorrect character
    encoding in a lot of cases.
    """
    FAIL_ENCODING = 'ISO-8859-1'
    config = config or Configuration()
    useragent = config.browser_user_agent
    timeout = config.request_timeout

    if response is not None:
        if response.encoding != FAIL_ENCODING:
            return response.text
        return response.content

    try:
        html = None

        response = requests.get(
            url=url, **get_request_kwargs(timeout, useragent))

        if response.encoding != FAIL_ENCODING:
            html = response.text
        else:
            html = response.content

        if config.http_success_only:
            response.raise_for_status()  # fail if other than "ok" response

        if html is None:
            html = ''

        return html
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        log.debug('%s on %s' % (e, url))
        return ''
```

based on the code above a call to response.raise_for_status() should result into an exception which is not handled, thus program should have failed.

To prove the same I also tried using requests directly:

```
from newspaper import Article
from newspaper import Config, Article, Source
import requests

c = Config()
c.browser_user_agent = 'test/1.1'
c.http_success_only = True

URL = 'http://rss.cnn1sdfs.com/c/35494/f/676993/s/4ddb6116/sc/14/l/0Ledition0Bcnn0N0C20A160C0A20C250Chealth0Ce0Ecigarette0Eexplodes0Ein0Emans0Epocket0Cindex0Bhtml0Deref0Fedition/story01.htm'

# a = Article(url=URL,config=c)
# a.download()

response = requests.get(URL)
response.raise_for_status()
```

and this program DOES fail!

Can you please help me understand why my first program doesn't fail and how to fix it? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Due to exception handling inside get_html program does not fail and simply returns empty HTML object. The error is lost in abstraction.